# Как установить разные цвета для QSurfaceDataRow в Q3DSurface?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Как установить разные цвета для определенных QSurfaceDataRow, которые находятся в QSurfaceDataArray на Q3DSurface?

Я могу установить для всех данных определенный цвет:

```
surfaceGraph->seriesList().at(0)->setBaseColor(Qt::red);
```

или раскрасить все градиентом.

Но мне необходимо раскрасить поверхность разными цветами. У меня есть пара для какой точки поверхности - её цвет.  Возможности сделать такую раскраску без создания текстуры? Если да, то как?

Вот пример с которым я работаю https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html